# R's signal package's filter not matching with Matlab's filter function

Tags: r, matlab

In Matlab, there is a 1-D `filter` function http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html .

In R's `signal` package, the description of its `filter` function states: `Generic ﬁltering function. The default is to ﬁlter with an ARMA ﬁlter of given coefﬁcients. The default ﬁltering operation follows Matlab/Octave conventions.`

However, the answers don't match if I give the same specification.

In MATLAB (correct answer):

```
x=[4 3 5 2 7 3]
filter(2/3,[1 -1/3],x,x(1)*1/3)
ans =
4.0000    3.3333    4.4444    2.8148    5.6049    3.8683
```

In R, if I follow Matlab/Octave's convention (incorrect answer):

```
library(signal)
x<-c(4,3,5,2,7,3)
filter(2/3,c(1,-1/3),x,x[1]*1/3)

Time Series:
Start = 1
End = 6
Frequency = 1
[1] 3.111111 3.037037 4.345679 2.781893 5.593964 3.864655
```

I tried a lot of other examples too. R's `signal` package's `filter` function doesn't appear to follow the Matlab/Octave conventions even though the document states it so. Perhaps, I'm using the `filter` function incorrectly in R. Can someone help me?

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to email the package maintainer. In most cases the maintainer lists their email address either on the CRAN package page or in the reference manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is in the documentation (shock!!!!)

## matlab:

The filter is a "Direct Form II Transposed"
    implementation of the standard difference equation:

```
a(1)*y(n) = b(1)*x(n) + b(2)*x(n-1) + ... + b(nb+1)*x(n-nb)
                      - a(2)*y(n-1) - ... - a(na+1)*y(n-na)
```

## If a(1) is not equal to 1, filter normalizes the filter  coefficients by a(1).

[emphasis mine]

## R:

```
a[1]*y[n] + a[2]*y[n-1] + … + a[n]*y[1] = b[1]*x[n] + b[2]*x[m-1] + … + b[m]*x[1]
```

Comment: not sure if I understand your answer, both look like the same equation to me, with `na=n-1` and `nb=m-1`

Comment: @uday  But I don't think `R` normalizes by `a[1]`  .  I'm happy to be corrected if I skimmed this too quickly.

Comment: I believe that this means that `a` is normalized by computing `a/a(1)` in the case where `a(1) != 1`.  However, here we do have `a(1) == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for lifting this issue a couple of years back... I bumped into it as well and think I got an answer. Essentially I think the optimization algos are different for R and Matlab.

If no guess is provided (that is, set the initial values to default which is zero for both R and Matlab), the results are very similar.

**R**

library(signal)

x<-c(4,3,5,2,7,3)

filter(2/3,cbind(1,-1/3),x, 0.00)

2.666667 2.888889 4.296296 2.765432 5.588477 3.862826

**Matlab**

x=[4 3 5 2 7 3]

filter(2/3,[1 -1/3],x,0.00)

2.6667    2.8889    4.2963    2.7654    5.5885    3.8628

**Now**, if we start tweaking the initial guess of the parameters, then the results will diverge.

**R**

library(signal)

x<-c(4,3,5,2,7,3)

filter(2/3,cbind(1,-1/3),x, 0.05)

2.683333 2.894444 4.298148 2.766049 5.588683 3.862894

**Matlab**

x=[4 3 5 2 7 3]

filter(2/3,[1 -1/3],x,0.05)

2.7167    2.9056    4.3019    2.7673    5.5891    3.8630

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I moved on to python and C# as a languages of choice since then, mostly for speed and more speed respectively. I hope others using R and Matlab can benefit.